Im trying to bid on this auction and i took a picture of the storage of the bike and im trying to figure out what it is and if its worth bidding on

This isnt my storage.this is a bidding unit.what do you think this bike is and its worth?

It's a Specialized Crosstrail Elite, 2016 MY.
https://bikeindex.org/bikes/69347
It will be a nice bike but valuable? Only you can decide whether it's good enough, you won't make a fortune reselling it. It looks clean though.


Oh sweet.thats cool.considering that the bid is only at $180 and the bike is worth $950 thats a good deal.not including all the other stuff in there that might be worth more thanks noise

Impressive find!
